# What is the maximum size iphone app for over the air download in 2014

Tags: ios, iphone, download, ad-hoc-distribution, over-the-air

I noticed that there are articles that suggest that the over the air download size is now 100 Mbytes ([Apple Increases Over-the-Air App Store Download Limit to 100MB](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCkQFjAA&url=http://www.macrumors.com/2013/09/18/apple-increases-over-the-air-app-store-download-limit-to-100mb/&ei=5LjiUoOaBqaO2AXbpoFw&usg=AFQjCNEsglGp1OyF9eIxddz67Z6dgKl3ng&sig2=YUC333Uqcw_6Aw0KCbcp3Q&bvm=bv.59930103,d.b2I)). However, I have not successfully been able to perform a download of a 54Mbyte app from an ad hoc distribution. When attempting to download the app, it sits in a perpetual state of "Waiting...". Before I try to squeeze out 4 Mbytes from my app before submitting it to Apple, I would like to know if the problem I am having is just a problem with ad hoc distributions, or if there is still a limit of 50 Mbytes for over the air download.

Comment: The download limit does not apply to ad-hoc distributions, only to App store downloads.  I think your problem resides somewhere else.

Comment: @Putz1103 Well, I am not sure I have a problem elsewhere. As soon as I turn on WiFi, the download of the app in the "waiting..." state begins and completes successfully. Also, if I cut the app size down under 50 MBytes, the app will download over cellular (just tried it by deleting a few iPad-hd images from the load). So do you think this is just a function of the ad hoc distribution, or is it a hard limit by the cellular carrier?

Comment: In that case I couldn't tell you.